# Как убрать /home при переходе на эту страницу через навигацию сайта

Tags: .htaccess

У сайта индексная страница home.html. Я в интернете откопал настройку .htaccess файла, чтобы убрать /home.html на конце. Вот что у меня прописано:

```
DirectoryIndex home.html
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
   RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
   RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
```

Когда заходишь на сайт, то вроде все ок. Но если потыкать по другим страницам сайта и снова вернуться на home, то появляется /home на конце. Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно прописать, чтобы индексная страница всегда была без лишних символов.

Comment: если `/home` появляется на конце после того как Вы потыкали, то `/home` стоит искать в ссылках, которые вы генерите и указываете для перехода.

Comment: Сайт написан только на html/css. /home появляется если в навигации сайта нажать на HOME. При первоначальном заходе на сайт никаких хоумов нету. В ссылке нету никаких /home строка HOME в навигации ссылается на сам файл home.html. Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы индексная страница всегда была чистой?

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример ссылки (тега `<a></a>`) на домашнюю страницу

Comment: <a href="home.html">HOME</a>

Comment: у вас все html файлы лежат в корневой директории или нет? Вы знаете разницу между абсолютными и относительными ссылками?

Comment: 3 файла навигации лежат в корневой директории (home.html, work.html, contact.html). И есть еще отдельная папка с html файлами не в корневой директории. Про абсолютные и относительные ссылки не знаю. Абсолютная это которая имеет адрес индексной страницы в интернете, а не файла?

Comment: Да надо просто все перевести на абсолютные ссылки. Я почему то не знал раньше про них=) Как-то не натыкался на инфу. Указывал в ссылках просто файлы. Просто на HOME вписать адрес индексной страницы, ну и остальное наверное тоже переведу на абсолютные. Спасибо за помощь. Я почему-то думал, что это надо в htaccess файле что-то делать=)